# howto disable balancermembers by default

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, load-balancing

I'm using an Apache 2.2 loadbalancer like this

```
<Proxy balancer://xxxx>
  BalancerMember ajp://host1:8009/xxxx
  BalancerMember ajp://host2:8009/xxxx
  BalancerMember ajp://host3:8009/xxxx
</Proxy>
```

Is there a way to tell apache that e.g. host2 is in disabled disabled on startup? Of course one can comment out the respective BalancerMember line, but then there's no way to reenable it using then balancer-manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, do the following:

```
BalancerMember ajp://host2:8009/xxxx status=D
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it. Do you know where all the options of BalancerMember are documented? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#balancermember should be the expected place for this - but nothing there.

Comment: Yes, all of the options can be found here, they are all the ProxyPass options.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass